# Only INSERT to all 4 tables successfully or not at all

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, sql-insert

At the moment I am trying to insert into 4 separate tables using 4 separate INSERT commands.

I only want this to happen if all 4 of the INSERTS are successful. If any of the INSERT's fail then I do not want any of the data to be entered into the DB.

At the moment I have a very ugly looking php IF statement which I'd rather not include here as I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: it's called a `transaction`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm and you DEFINITELY don't want to be simulating them with client-side code. highly unreliable and dangerous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use transaction:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect(...)
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn);
//do some inserts
if($insert1 && $insert2 ..) {
    mysqli_commit($conn);
} else {
    mysqli_rollback($conn);
}
```

Depending on your database configs, you should disable autocommit: `mysqli_autocommit($conn, false);`

Comment: Rollback sounds exactly what I am looking for. 

Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, whe are here to help. It this answer helped you, please mark as accepted to help the next one with the same problem.

Comment: Just trying to implement it now before I mark it :)